# Staying in same page, after inserting data in MySQL using PHP using POST method

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having a simple problem, but I don't know how to overcome it.

Here's my page with the form

```
<div id="register">
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" width="1000px" >
<tr>
<td height="300px" width="300px" align="center">
</td>
<td height="300px" width="400px" align="center" background="Images/panel2.png">
<form action="reg_conn.php" method="post">
<FIELDSET>
<LEGEND>Register</LEGEND><P>
   <table width="350px" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center">
      <tr>
      <td align="center" width="50px"/>
      <td align="center" width="100px">
           <label for="username" >UserName:</label>
      </td>
      <td align="center" width="50px"/>
      <td align="center" width="100px">
             <input type="text" name="username" class="textfield"/>
      </td> 
      <td align="center" width="50px"/>        
      </tr>
      <tr>
      <td colspan="5" align="center" height="10px"/>
      </tr> 
      <tr>
      <td align="center" width="50px"/>
      <td align="center" width="100px">
           <label for="name" >Name:</label>
      </td>
      <td align="center" width="50px"/>
      <td align="center" width="100px">
             <input type="text" name="name" class="textfield"/>
      </td> 
      <td align="center" width="50px"/>        
      </tr> 
      <tr>
      <td colspan="5" align="center" height="10px"/>
      </tr> 
      <tr>
      <td align="center" width="50px"/>
      <td align="center" width="100px">
           <label for="email" >Email:</label>
      </td>
      <td align="center" width="50px"/>
      <td align="center" width="100px">
             <input type="text" name="email" class="textfield"/>
      </td> 
      <td align="center" width="50px"/>        
      </tr> 
      <tr>
      <td colspan="5" align="center" height="10px"/>
      </tr> 
      <tr>
      <td align="center" width="50px"/>
      <td align="center" width="100px">
           <label for="password" >PassWord:</label>
      </td>
      <td align="center" width="50px"/>
      <td align="center" width="100px">
             <input type="password" name="password" class="textfield"/>
      </td> 
      <td align="center" width="50px"/>        
      </tr>
      <tr>
      <td colspan="5" align="center" height="10px"/>
      </tr> 
      <tr>
      <td align="center" width="50px"/>
      <td align="center" width="100px">
           <label for="security_q" >Security Question:</label>
      </td>
      <td align="center" width="50px"/>
      <td align="center" width="100px">
              <select name="security_q" class="dropdown" style="width: 100px" >
                    <option value="My 1st Teacher">My 1st Teacher</option>
                    <option value="My 1st Pet">My 1st Teacher</option>
                    <option value="My 1st Crush">My 1st Crush</option>
              </select>     
      </td> 
      <td align="center" width="50px"/>        
      </tr> 
      <tr>
      <td colspan="5" align="center" height="10px"/>
      </tr> 
      <tr>
      <td align="center" width="50px"/>
      <td align="center" width="100px">
           <label for="security_a" >Security Answer:</label>
      </td>
      <td align="center" width="50px"/>
      <td align="center" width="100px">
            <input type="text" name="security_a" class="textfield"/>
      </td> 
      <td align="center" width="50px"/>        
      </tr> 
      <tr>
      <td colspan="5" align="center" height="10px"/>
      </tr> 
      <tr>
      <td align="center" width="50px"/>
      <td align="center" width="250px" colspan="3">
           <input type="submit" class="button" style="width: 200px; height: 20px;" />
      </td>
      <td align="center" width="50px"/>
      </tr> 
    </table>    
</FIELDSET>
</form>
</td>
<td height="300px" width="300px" align="center"/>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

And my reg_conn.php file is as follows:

```
<?php
include('connection.php');
$sql="INSERT INTO candidate_register_table (username, name, email, password, security_q, security_a)
VALUES
('$_POST[username]','$_POST[name]','$_POST[email]','$_POST[password]','$_POST[security_q]','$_POST[security_a]')";

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Now when I submit, the page is redirected to the reg_conn.php file. I don't want that; I want to stay on the previous page. How can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please follow Saswat's comment about SQL Injection.

You can add the following line after mysql_close($con);

```
header('Location: http://www.YOURWEBPAGE.com');
```

That will redirect to the page of your choice.

Comment: thnx buddy, but i got an error using header it says somethng like thuis:::Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\wamp\www\ShubhMangalam\reg_conn.php:9) in C:\wamp\www\ShubhMangalam\reg_conn.php on line 20

Answer (score 4):

What you're looking for is called a [Post-Redirect-Get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get). Upon successful submission to your database, you redirect the browser back to the final destination.

First thing's first though, protect against injection attacks:

```
include('connection.php'); 

$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
$securityq = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['security_q']);
$securitya = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['security_a']);


// Use filtered values here, never direct from $_POST!!!!!
$sql="INSERT INTO candidate_register_table (username, name, email, password, security_q, security_a)
VALUES ('$username','$name','$email','$password','$security_q','$security_a')";

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
{
   // Don't die(). Instead redirect with error.
   $err=1;
}

mysql_close($con);

// Set an error parameter if there was a problem...
// this is optional, since a failure of mysql_query() would indicate a code problem
// rather than a problem with the user's input.
if (isset($err)) {

  // And redirect back to the form with the error in the querystring
  header("Location: http://example.com/form.php?err=1");
  exit();
}
else {
  // No error...
  // And redirect back to the form...
  header("Location: http://example.com/form.php");
  exit();
}
```

On the form page, if you want to display an error to the user, you may do something like:

```
if (isset($_GET['err'])) {
  echo "an error occurred...";
}
```

More robust implementations would set an error message into `$_SESSION` and then `unset()` it after displaying on screen.

Answer (score 1):

You can, if you want, have a single page do both the form presentation and submission handling:

```
<?php

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
   ... process form data here ...
}

?>

.... html form goes here ...
```

That way, once the submission is completed, the form just gets displayed again, and the users stays at the same URL.

Answer (score 0):

```
$field_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['field_name']);

$sql = sprintf("INSERT INTO `table_name`(`field_name`)VALUES('$field_name')");
$que = mysql_query($sql);
if(!$que)
{
    echo "No";
}
else
{
    header("location:../yourpage.php"); 
}
```

You can use this code for redirection.

("location:../yourpage.php")

Change yourpage.php as your page name where you want to redirect after data insertion.